# going from 5volt 1A to equivalent from a 3V CR2 Battery

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, dc, capacitance

I have a small camera with wifi that runs off a 3V CR2 battery. I'm trying to run it from line voltage. Could not find any small transformers that go to 3volt 750mA. 
I have an Apple transformer for the iphone it outputs 5volt 1A. (I'm getting 5.33V on the crappy tester)
I've tested a fully charged 3v CR2 and it puts out 3.24volts ; I bought a NTE1904 which has a Vo 3.3V Io of 1A; when i hook it up to the breadboard I'm getting 3.25 volt output.

The mfgr of the camera said on their website that this is a 3V 750mA device; the device with the battery gives off considerable heat and only last a 1.5 hours on the battery.

When I plug it into the output of the voltage regulator straight the light comes on but it wifi doesn't work (bad because its the only way to connect to it); when i switch back to battery she works like a champ. I put 10mu caps on the output side  but light didnt even come on.

Am i missing a major concept. I'm kind of a newbie. would appreciate any help.

[image: overview of the problem]

spec sheet of NTE1904
 http://www.nteinc.com/specs/1900to1999/pdf/nte1904.pdf
******************************[image]
Camera Specifications 
•   VGA 640x480, QVGA 320x240, QQVGA 160x120, up to 30fps 
•   F2.8 
•   View Angle: 60 degree 
•   Focusing: 20cm to Infinity

Video Recorder 
•   Motion JPEG 
•   Compression mode : standard, high 
•   Typical bit rate: (VGA): standard (2500 kbps), high (1600 kbps) (QVGA): standard (1100 kbps), high (800 kbps) (QQVGA): standard (600 kbps), high (400 kbps)

Video Snapshot 
•   JPEG 
•   Compression mode : standard, high

Wireless Interface 
•   IEEE 802.11b/g 2.4GHz ISM Band

Wireless Security 
•   WEP 64/128, WPA, WPA2

Wireless Range 
•   Infrastructure: 20m (Typical) 
•   Adhoc: 7.5m (Typical)

Wireless performance* 
•   Infrastructure: 54Mbps, max. connection rate 
•   Adhoc: 11Mbps, max. connection rate 
•   Note: Wireless performance varies with distance and access point usage.

Antenna 
•   Single, internal

Dimension / Weight 
•   30mm(Diameter) x 35mm(L) 
•   100g

Power Supply / Consumption 
•   Battery operated 
•   Voltage: 3.0V 
•   Power: 750mAH (CR2) 
•   Current consumption: 320mA (typical); 350mA (maximum)

RoHS 
•   RoHS Compliant

User interface 
•   Menu driven via Embedded Web server on module

Comment: It would help if you could post links to the datasheet for the camera and a schematic of the NTE1904-based circuit that you've designed.

Comment: A close up photo of your breadboard circuit would be helpful also.

Comment: Measure the battery voltage when connected to the camera.  Measure the voltage of  the regulator when connected to the camera.  Compare and post.  If possible, measure currents as well.

Comment: Some chargers do not provide full current without negotiation with brand specific devices.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check to see if the NTE1904 can operate off of a 5V supply -> if not you need a LDO (Low Drop Out)

2) make sure it's not over heating and cutting out.  (5-3)[v]*1[A] = 2W -> heat sink.

3) Batteries are really good at handling peak currents, so the start up inrush current may be too high for the device.  That means you may have to use a device that can put out more current than the nominal rating. -> if you have a scope and current sensing resistor you could capture that.

Those are the three big things to look for.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a camera which used to be sold at Jaycar electronics in Australia (this was about 4 years ago unfortunately). I understand they also offered a cradle which could power the camera from USB. You could see whether a cradle is available for the camera.

See https://www.jaycar.com.au/wi-fi-remote-wireless-ip-camera/p/QC3368

https://www.jaycar.com.au/cradle-adaptors-for-wi-fi-wireless-camera-qc3368/p/QC3369

From memory, the cradle plugged directly into the battery socket so I would not be surprised if the camera is capable of operating directly from 5V.

*I have not tested this and would be equally unsurprised if the camera does not like 5V at all.*

Answer (score 0):

When you measure the expected 3V at the circuit, you will find that the poor connections on a solderless breadboard cannot pass 750mA without a high voltage loss.